# slurm_apply a RefClass method from within a RefClass method

Tags: r, slurm, reference-class

EDIT:  New version of `rslurm` makes the solution very easy.  See my answer below.

Apologies for the somewhat longer than desired MWE, and a title that I realize after submitting the question may be needlessly complicated.  I believe the real issue is getting the environment of a RefClass object into `rslurm::slurm_apply`.

### MWE

Here I define a toy reference class called `BankAccount`.  It has two fields and two methods.

The fields are `transactions`, a list of all transactions associated with the account and `suspicion_threshold` the value above which the bank will investigate the transaction.

The two methods are `is_suspicious` which compares the `transactions` with the `suspicion_threshold` on the local machine and `is_suspicious_slurm`, which uses `rslurm::slurm_apply` to spread many calls to `is_suspicious` over a cluster of computers managed by SLURM.  You can imagine if there were many transactions or if the `is_suspicious` function were more complex, this might be necessary.

So, here's the setup

```
BankAccount <- setRefClass(
    Class = 'BankAccount',
    fields = list(
        transactions = 'numeric',
        suspicion_threshold = 'numeric'
    )
)

BankAccount$methods(
    is_suspicious = function(start_idx = 1, stop_idx = length(transactions)) {

    return(start_idx + which(transactions[start_idx:stop_idx] > suspicion_threshold) - 1)

    }
)

BankAccount$methods(
    is_suspicious_slurm = function(num_nodes) {

        usingMethods(is_suspicious)

        t <- length(transactions)
        t_per_n <- floor(t/num_nodes)
        starts <- seq(from = 1, length.out = num_nodes, by = t_per_n)
        stops <- seq(from = t_per_n, length.out = num_nodes,  by = t_per_n)
        stops[num_nodes] <- t

        sjob <- rslurm::slurm_apply(f = is_suspicious,
                                    params = data.frame(start_idx = starts,
                                                        stop_idx = stops),
                                    nodes = num_nodes,
                                    add_objects = .self)

        results_list <- rslurm::get_slurm_out(slr_job = sjob,
                                              outtype = "raw",
                                              wait = TRUE)

        return(unlist(results_list))
    }
)
```

Now, on my local machine I can run:

```
library(RCexampleforSE)

set.seed(27599)

b <- BankAccount$new()
b$transactions <- rnorm(n = 500)
b$suspicion_threshold <- 2

b$is_suspicious()
b$is_suspicious_slurm(num_nodes = 3)
```

and it works as expected:

> 62 103 155 171 182 188 297 398 493 499

If I run:

```
b$is_suspicious_slurm(num_nodes = 3)
```

I get an error, since my personal computer is not connected to a SLURM cluster.

> sh: squeue: command not found
>   Cannot submit; no SLURM workload manager on path
>   Submission scripts output in directory _rslurm_13ba46e3c70b0
>   Error in rslurm::get_slurm_out(slr_job = sjob, outtype = "raw", wait = TRUE): 
>       slr_job has not been submitted

If I logon to my university cluster, which uses SLURM, and run the same script, the setup and local methods work just as they did on my personal computer.  When I run:

```
b$is_suspicious_slurm(num_nodes = 3)
```

it sends jobs to the cluster, as hoped for:

> Submitted batch job 6363868

But these jobs error immediately with the following error message in `slurm_0.out`, `slurm_1.out`, and `slurm_2.out`:

> Error in attr(, "mayCall") : argument 1 is empty
>   Execution halted

### Thoughts and Attempts

I figure the job probably needs, but doesn't have available, the `BankAccount` object.  So I tried passing it in as `add_objects` parameter to `rslurm::slurm_apply`:

```
sjob <- rslurm::slurm_apply(f = is_suspicious,
                                    params = data.frame(start_idx = starts,
                                                        stop_idx = stops),
                                    nodes = num_nodes,
                                    add_objects = .self)
```

I also tried it in quotes and inside `eval()`, neither of which worked.

How can I make the object accessible to the worker jobs created with `rslurm::slurm_apply`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 0.4.0 of `rslurm` completely solved this problem.

Define `is_suspicious_slurm()` as:

```
BankAccount$methods(
    is_suspicious_slurm = function(num_nodes) {

        usingMethods(is_suspicious)

        t <- length(transactions)
        t_per_n <- floor(t/num_nodes)
        starts <- seq(from = 1, length.out = num_nodes, by = t_per_n)
        stops <- seq(from = t_per_n, length.out = num_nodes,  by = t_per_n)
        stops[num_nodes] <- t

        sjob <- rslurm::slurm_apply(f = is_suspicious,
                                    params = data.frame(start_idx = starts,
                                                        stop_idx = stops),
                                    nodes = num_nodes)

        results_list <- rslurm::get_slurm_out(slr_job = sjob,
                                              outtype = "raw",
                                              wait = TRUE)

        return(unlist(results_list))
    }
)
```

The only change is that in the call to `rslurm::slurm_apply`, the `add_objects` parameter is not specified.  It does not need to be specified because as @Ian [pointed out](https://github.com/SESYNC-ci/rslurm/pull/11):

"...you don't need to pass self at all when slurm_apply sends the serialized function, which appears to include both ".self" and "transactions" in the enclosing environment."

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: OP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47024925/687112) is all you need to know.

The `add_objects` parameter is used for passing a character vector, not the objects themselves. All the objects are then saved in one RData file, assuming they can be found by name. In theory, you should be able to use `add_objects = c('.self')` within your method definition.

The key here is, "assuming they can be found". I will edit this post once a pending update to the rslurm package (which should make that finding more successful) is released.

Be very careful passing objects to cluster nodes: they do not come back. Not only will any side effects be lost, there's no inter-node communication implemented by rslurm.

Also be careful with `which` :) Your `is_suspicious` method will be wrong for arguments that don't start at 1. Try this version:

```
BankAccount$methods(
    is_suspicious = function(i = 1:length(transactions)) {
        idx <- which(transactions[i] > suspicion_threshold)
        i[idx]
    }
)
```

Comment: you are correct there was an error in my implementation of `is_suspicious()`, but I fixed it in a different way.